# How to send a signal to the main thread in python without using join?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, signals, python-multithreading

I Am trying to send a signal from a child thread to the main thread in a multi-threaded program (cannot use multi-processes). Unfortunately even after exhausting all the reading materials available online (which I could find), I Am unable to get a clear idea of how to do so. I Am a beginner to signals AND to python so please bear with me and explain as you would to a novice.
I cannot use the join method in the process, since I want both the threads to be running simultaneously.
Here is the code that I found related to the topic here - http://pymotw.com/2/signal/#signals-and-threads
and it doesn't really work for me.

```
import signal
import threading
import os
import time

def signal_handler(num, stack):
    print 'Received signal %d in %s' % (num, threading.currentThread())

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, signal_handler)

def wait_for_signal():
    print 'Waiting for signal in', threading.currentThread()
    signal.pause()
    print 'Done waiting'

# Start a thread that will not receive the signal
receiver = threading.Thread(target=wait_for_signal, name='receiver')
receiver.start()
time.sleep(0.1)

def send_signal():
    print 'Sending signal in', threading.currentThread()
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGUSR1)

sender = threading.Thread(target=send_signal, name='sender')
sender.start()
sender.join()

# Wait for the thread to see the signal (not going to happen!)
print 'Waiting for', receiver
signal.alarm(2)
receiver.join()
```

Please explain with a multi-threaded example if possible.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12):

Signals and threads really, really don't play nice together.

Consider use an `Event` or other synchronization mechanism.  The following example creates an 'event' object, then passes it to two threads.  One waits for two seconds, then signals the other to print out a message then exit.

### source

```
import threading, time

def flagger_thread(event):
    """
    wait for two seconds, then make 'event' fire
    """
    time.sleep(2)
    event.set()

def waiter_thread(event):
    print("Waiting for event")
    if event.wait(5):
        print("event set.")
    else:
        print("Timed out.")

stop_event = threading.Event()
threading.Thread(target=flagger_thread, args=[stop_event]).start()
threading.Thread(target=waiter_thread, args=[stop_event]).start()

# wait for all threads to exit
for t in threading.enumerate():
    if t != threading.current_thread():
        t.join()
```

### output

```
Waiting for event
event set.
```