# Python threading: make the main thread report the progress

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I run some jobs in parallel, which can sometime take a long time, so I want the main thread to report on the progress. For example, each hour.

Below is the simplified version of what I came up with. The code will run `test_function` in 2 threads with arguments from `input_arguments`. Every 5 seconds it will print % of the jobs finished.

```
import threading
import queue
import time


def test_function(x):
    time.sleep(4)
    print("Finished ", x)


num_processes = 2
input_arguments = range(10)

# Define a worker which will continuously execute function taking input parameters from the queue
def worker():
    while True:
        x = q.get()
        if x is None:
            break
        test_function(x)
        q.task_done()

# Initialize queue and the threads
q = queue.Queue()
threads = []
for i in range(num_processes):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

# Create a queue of input parameters for function
for item in input_arguments:
    q.put(item)

# Report progress every 5 seconds
report_progress(q)

# stop workers
for i in range(num_processes):
    q.put(None)
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Where `report_progress` is defined as following

```
def report_progress(q):
    qsize_init = q.qsize()
    while not q.empty():
        time.sleep(5)
        portion_finished = 1 - q.qsize() / qsize_init
        print("run_parallel: {:.1%} jobs are finished".format(portion_finished))
```

However, I want to report the progress every hour instead of 5 seconds, and if all jobs are finished, the program might just be idle for many minutes.

Another possibility is to define `report_progress` differently:

```
def report_progress(q):
    qsize_init = q.qsize()
    time_start = time.time()
    while not q.empty():
        current_time = time.time()
        if current_time - time_start > 5:
            portion_finished = 1 - q.qsize() / qsize_init
            print("run_parallel: {:.1%} jobs are finished".format(portion_finished))
            time_start = time.time()
```

I am worried that constantly checking this condition will drain CPU resources, small portion, but on a scale of hours it could be a lot.

Is there a standard way of handling this?

Python: 3.6

Comment: Maybe instead of polling you should depend on events. In this case you would need to set event timeout to 1h and if the event occurs you would continue.
[a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25369943/1763370)

Comment: the standard way for polling for many events simultaneously (like waiting for 1 hour timeout and for death of the process) is IO multiplexing. In python the most user-friendly interface to this stuff is **asyncio** module.

Comment: But using the standard way may be too complicated for your rather simple case. You may just: (1) - sleep 10 seconds, (2) - check the thread status, exit the program if it's dead, (3) if an hour passed since last progress report, calculate and print a new one, (4) goto (1)

Comment: @AndriyMaletsky
I already have some code based on `threading` module, and I wanted to make a small addition on top of it. If I use  `asyncio`, I will have to rewrite it all, is it correct?

The idea from your second comment looks like a good compromise

Comment: You are correct, asyncio is hard to integrate with existing code. The quite common pattern is the "manager" process running asyncio, it schedules work, checks for progress, checks if the all jobs have been cancelled by user, in other words does lots of things at a time. And the "worker" processes, which are launched as subprocesses, thus isolated from asyncio. Such approach allows not to rewrite worker code

Comment: That sounds like a good features, I will look into this package if I need something more advanced in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I will use a simple solution, suggested in the comments by @Andriy Maletsky.

Main thread will check every few seconds if the q is not empty yet, and it will print a progress message if it has past more than 1 hour since the last report.

```
time_between_reports = 3600
time_between_checks = 5
def report_progress_until_finished(q):
    qsize_init = q.qsize()
    last_report_time = time.time()
    while not q.empty():
        time_elapsed = time.time() - last_report_time
        if time_elapsed > time_between_reports:
            portion_finished = 1 - q.qsize() / qsize_init
            print("run_parallel: {:.1%} jobs are finished".format(portion_finished))
            last_report_time = time.time()
        time.sleep(time_between_checks)
```