# Is there a way to execute a function on main thread in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have the following problem. The app spawns several threads (asynchronously). Each thread is responsible for a specific task, which is executed periodically. For example, one thread checks every N seconds if there are new records in the database to process. If there are, it then starts working on that (automatically typing and clicking on a screen). Before this process starts, I want to show a popup to notify me, that the app is about to take over my mouse and keyboard. The problem is, that showing a popup requires us to be on the main thread (which we are obviously not).
Here is the snippet:
in ready function:

```
threading.Timer(10, self.check_periodically).start()
```

inside that function, I only have (for now):

```
pymsgbox.alert(timeout=5000)
```

Which gives me an error:

```
2019-12-09 10:52:23.009 Python[1676:5003701] WARNING: NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread! This will throw an exception in the future. Called from (
0   AppKit                              0x0000000105e016ef -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 371
1   AppKit                              0x0000000105dfebc1 -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1416
2   AppKit                              0x0000000105dfe633 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 42
3   Tk                                  0x0000000105c0f3b1 TkMacOSXMakeRealWindowExist + 766
4   Tk                                  0x0000000105c0efdc TkWmMapWindow + 56
5   Tk                                  0x0000000105b82d5d Tk_MapWindow + 155
6   Tk                                  0x0000000105b8aead TkInstallFrameMenu + 267
7   Tcl                                 0x0000000105afc4cc TclServiceIdle + 75
8   Tcl                                 0x0000000105ae3bb6 Tcl_DoOneEvent + 353
9   _tkinter.cpython-36m-darwin.so      0x0000000104ea8aa1 _tkinter_tkapp_mainloop + 209
10  Python                              0x00000001007a47b8 _PyCFunction_FastCallDict + 552
11  Python                              0x000000010082e164 call_function + 612
12  Python                              0x000000010082fb74 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 5604
13  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64 0x000000010485dba6 __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 6806
14  Python                              0x000000010082d500 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2720
15  Python                              0x000000010082dd2b fast_function + 219
16  Python                              0x000000010082e14b call_function + 587
17  Python                              0x000000010082fb74 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 5604
18  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64 0x000000010485dba6 __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 6806
19  Python                              0x000000010082d500 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2720
20  Python                              0x000000010082dd2b fast_function + 219
21  Python                              0x000000010082e14b call_function + 587
22  Python                              0x0000000100830096 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6918
23  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64 0x000000010485dba6 __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 6806
24  Python                              0x000000010082d500 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2720
25  Python                              0x000000010082dd2b fast_function + 219
26  Python                              0x000000010082e14b call_function + 587
27  Python                              0x0000000100830096 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6918
28  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64 0x000000010485dba6 __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 6806
29  Python                              0x000000010082e556 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 838
30  Python                              0x0000000100748a54 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 356
31  Python                              0x0000000100749120 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 208
32  Python                              0x0000000100748443 PyObject_Call + 99
33  Python                              0x00000001008305f6 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 8294
34  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64 0x000000010485dba6 __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 6806
35  Python                              0x000000010082deae fast_function + 606
36  Python                              0x000000010082e14b call_function + 587
37  Python                              0x000000010082fb74 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 5604
38  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64 0x000000010485dba6 __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 6806
39  Python                              0x000000010082deae fast_function + 606
40  Python                              0x000000010082e14b call_function + 587
41  Python                              0x000000010082fb74 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 5604
42  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64 0x000000010485dba6 __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 6806
43  Python                              0x000000010082e556 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 838
44  Python                              0x0000000100748a54 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 356
45  Python                              0x0000000100749120 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 208
46  Python                              0x0000000100748443 PyObject_Call + 99
47  Python                              0x00000001008305f6 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 8294
48  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64 0x000000010485cbfb __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 2795
49  Python                              0x000000010082e556 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 838
50  Python                              0x0000000100748a54 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 356
51  Python                              0x0000000100749120 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 208
52  Python                              0x0000000100748443 PyObject_Call + 99
53  Python                              0x00000001007c3d83 slot_tp_call + 67
54  Python                              0x0000000100748443 PyObject_Call + 99
55  Python                              0x00000001008865e7 t_bootstrap + 71
56  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000101445d36 _pthread_start + 125
57  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010144258f thread_start + 15
)
```

Of course, if I run `pymsgbox.alert(timeout=5000)` on the main thread, it works like a charm.

Is there any standard way to achieve that?
Comming from OS X development and Java, this is a no-brainer, but I've spent so many hours debugging this, that my programming skills are getting questioned here... :)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25155267/how-to-send-a-signal-to-the-main-thread-in-python-without-using-join) post can help you out. My bet is to use `Event`.

Comment: @Kendoka That post did, in fact, help me out, thank you for that. I'll wait a couple more days and if nobody posts a clean solution, I'll post it myself. It's a bit hackish, but it's more than enough for me to work with.